# Dynamic Facebook Thumbinails on Wall

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I have a problem with the dynamic generation of thumbnail images on Facebook.  I need to put a unique image on every subpage.  I have page links like:

- www.name.com/1234
- www.name.com/23
- etc.

And on every page I put a unique meta property="og:image", for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.name.com/images/23.png"/>
```

But Facebook only sees the default og:image defined on the main page.

What can i do? Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a dynamic "og:url" as well.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.one.com/[YOUR_DYNAMIC_PATH]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.one.com/[YOUR_DYNAMIC_IMAGE]?>" />
```

Hope this helps.